# classify batch of images using tensorflow mobilenet retrain example

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a classification net by using *Tensorflow MobileNet* `retrain.py` example file (in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)

When I use the trained net, i managed to run only a single image at a time (the input is tensorflow 4d array shape [1, 128, 128, 3])

Don't know if it means anything, but the train process used *train batch* flag `--train_batch_size=100`

When i try to classify a batch of images (for example, tensorflow 4d array shape [2, 128, 128, 3] to `'input'` layer), i get the following error:
`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 128, 128, 3) for Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(1, 128, 128, 3)'`

(before running this trained net session, i am using a preprocess tensorflow session that prepares the images for this net (resize, normalise, etc.)

Does anyone knows what should i do in order to run a batch of images over such a net or how can i configure the `retrain.py` file that would create a net that allows batch run?